# z-indexs for position:fixed

Tags: css

I want to put a modal popup on my website. It's html is like this:

```
<div id="thePopup" class="popup" style="display:none;">
    <div class="popup-shadow">.</div>
    <h3>My Details</h3>
    <p>Message....</p>
</div>
```

Then I have css (well, actually SASS, which compiles to css.) like this:

```
.popup {
    z-index:10000;
    width:32em;
    position:absolute;
    left:20%;
    width:60%;

    .popup-shadow {
        position:fixed;
        top:0%;
        left:0%;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:9000;

        background-color:#999999;
        /* I have yet to do it, but the shadow will be slightly transparent */
    }
}
```

There is a button that sets `thePopup` to display:block when the user clicks it. The popup is nested inside one of the content panels on my website. it is `position:absolute` so it appears above its parent panel when it is visible. I don't set `thePopup` to `position:fixed` as it could be bigger than the height of the users screen, and I want them to be able to scroll up and down on it. However, I want to darken everywhere on the screen that isn't the popup - to indicate to the user that they need to interact with it.

This is where I run into problems - `popup-shadow` is being rendered infront of `thePopup`, despite it having a lower z-level. I don't know why this is. If I take away the `popup-shadow` div, `thepopup` appears on screen as expected. Does anyone have any idea why this is? Will a child div always be rendered on top of its parent, even if it has a lower z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems that the child elements of a div will always be rendered in front of the div, even if the div has a higher z-level. My solution was to put the `popup-shadow` div in a different location, and use a pair of javascript functions to ensure it was always made visible/hidden when popups were displayed and hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index:-1;` instead of `z-index:9000;` for  shadow div and `z-index:1;` instead of `z-index:10000;` for popup div

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/QfbUY/

Comment: That half works - the child elements of `popup` are infront of the shadow, but popup itself is not. This is clear if `popup` is given a background-color in the css.

Comment: If you set `position:inherit` for popup box, Then it comes up: see the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/kFaYy/

Comment: The problem is that in that context, position:inherit means position:static. I need `popup` to be absolutely positioned to make it work correctly as a popup. It looks like there is no easy solution to this - I'll have to make `popup-shadow` not a child element of `popup`, and handle it in a different way.